# Initial pen position in freetype?

Tags: fonts, truetype, freetype, freetype2

After drawing a glyph with freetype the pen is advanced as follows:

```
pen.x += face->glyph->advance.x;
pen.y += face->glyph->advance.y;
```

My question is, how do you set the initial pen position of the first character, relative to the upper left bound of the drawing surface?

`{0,0}` isn't correct, as it would draw the first line mostly above the top of the drawing surface, and too close to the left bound.

I suspect it is some combination of:

```
struct FT_FaceRec {
  ...
  FT_BBox           bbox;

  FT_UShort         units_per_EM;
  FT_Short          ascender;
  FT_Short          descender;
  FT_Short          height;

  FT_Short          max_advance_width;
  FT_Short          max_advance_height;
  ...
}
```

but it isn't very clear.

Comment: Do you plan to use a [very tall font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128095/whats-the-tallest-unicode-glyph)? If the first character sticks out to the left – say, a swash italic lowercase `f` –  do you want to move it to the right so it's entirely visible? Always the same font and size? Is this for interactive input, or static text? In determining the y offset, do you need to cater for accents? On capitals? Including Vietnamese (multiple stacked accents)? Including zalgo text? (... *lotsa* stacked accents..)

Answer (score 0):

For the record I ended up using as initial pen position:

pen.x = 0;
pen.y = -face->size->metrics.ascender;

This seems to be the appropriate minimal border to the topleft of the origin of the first glyph.

Further, using face->size->metrics.descender past the last baseline (origin of the last glyph), for the bottom border.  And using the x pen position after advancing (+= .advance.x) past the origin of the rightmost glyph as the minimal right side border.